# Android NDK error bash: ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/: Is a director

Tags: android, android-ndk

ubuntu kylin system
NDK version r10e
SDK version android-22
Details command：
`javah -d jni -classpath /home/king/ide/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-22/android.jar;../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/ com.lengking.ndk.MainActivity`
error :`bash: ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/: Is a director`
I did not find the answer on the Web

Comment: I do not know why the format become so,
But it is not necessary to Poor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoke your command under Linux. The shell interpreter `BASH` treat `;` as the command separator. The class path separator `;` is for Windows.

So you can change you command to following, it will work.

```
javah -d jni -classpath /home/king/ide/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-22/android.jar:../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/ com.lengking.ndk.MainActivity
```

Comment: I joined the classpath variable android.jar
Problem solving, by the way thanks under your